# How do I understand an object as a const name?

Tags: typescript

I have seen Typescript code that looks like this:

```
const { PUBLIC_JWKS } = event.secrets.PUBLIC_JWKS;
```

and I am having trouble understanding what this means.

My first question is:  Is this even a Typescript thing, or a holdover from Javascript?

Second: If it is a Typescript thing, what, exactly does it mean? It seems string to have an object be a `const` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My first question is: Is this even a Typescript thing, or a holdover from Javascript?

holdover from Javascript and it is called [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```
const { myId } = props;
```

is the same as :

```
const myId = props.myId
```

so here it is most probably :

```
const { PUBLIC_JWKS } = event.secrets;
```

or maybe `event.secrets.PUBLIC_JWKS` is an object with PUBLIC_JWKS `property` who knows

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned typescript code "that looks like this". So, is it exactly that code? Or are you improvising. Because...

I think this should be:

`const { PUBLIC_JWKS } = event.secrets`

No TypeScript here.

Just creating a new const variable PUBLIC_JWKS, and assigning it the value of `event.secrets.PUBLIC_JWKS;` (By extracting it from that property name)